# Fetch email id from a string

Tags: php

I have array containing strings in format like:

```
a@hotmail.com Entry ID: 12321
b@hotmail.com Entry ID: 12322 Entry ID: 12323
c@hotmail.com Entry ID: 12324 Entry ID: 12325 Entry ID: 12326
d@hotmail.com Entry ID: 12327 Entry ID: 12328
e@hotmail.com Entry ID: 12329 Entry ID: 123210
```

and I want to fetch only email address from each string & push into an array.

I tried http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?200875-extract-email-from-string-text-%28patterns%29

and many others from Stackoverflow but browser shows blank screen on **echo/print_r**

Comment: Look here for Email regexes:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

It even has the "The Official Standard: RFC 2822" supporting email regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the string always starts with a email adress. You can work like this:

```
foreach($emailArray as $value){ 
  $email = explode(" ",$value)[0];
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting here that the `someFunction()[0]` syntax is only valid since PHP 5.4

Answer (score 2):

You can [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string by a space and [`array_shit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) the first element. Something like:

```
$emailAddresses = array();
foreach($strings as $string) {
   $emailAddresses[] = array_shift(explode(' ', $string));
}
```

Avoid using a RegEx unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm making an assumption here that for each line, the seperator between the email and the other data is consistent - a single space.

Simply use the [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split each element by a single space and take the first element of the resulting split. That will be the email.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  $parts = explode(" ",$value);
  $email = $parts[0];
}
```

#### [Here is a live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bcbe073bd9275dd6cc2b77617ca7cea4dae40659)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `regex`.

```
preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**OutPut**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a@hotmail.com
    [1] => b@hotmail.com
    [2] => c@hotmail.com
    [3] => d@hotmail.com
    [4] => e@hotmail.com
)
```

Comment: This regex does not account for all email addresses. It will actually cause serious errors for emails like - `test+foo@example.com` - by only extracting `foo@example.com`; A totally different email address.